# Multiplicar dos numeros aleatorios hasta que den 0

Tags: python

Estoy aprendiendo sobre loops en Python y tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

> Escriba un programa en Python que genere dos números aleatorios con
>   valores enteros entre el -5 y 5 hasta que encuentre alguna iteración
>   en la cual la multiplicación de los dos números enteros sea igual a
>   cero. El programa debe mostrar por pantalla los números aleatorios que
>   se generaron.

Asumo que se realiza con un for loop y range, sin embargo no logro entender el desarrollo.

```
import random
producto = 0
for x in range(-5, 4):
    num1 = random.choice(x)
    num2 = random.choice(x)
    producto = num1 * num2
    if producto == 0:
        print("Se ha encontrado un 0 en la iteracion numero: ", n)
```

Ingrese el codigo que idee aunque creo que no sirve para nada.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido/a a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask]. Además puedes hacer el [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio. Si pudieras agregar el código de lo que has intentado tu pregunta sería mejor recibida. Te doy una pista: *debes usar un loop while*. Saludos

Comment: Antes de intentar pensar en la implementación te recomiendo resuelvas el algoritmo en un papel. Dime algo ¿Cuándo es que dos números multiplicados dan 0? Qué tienen esos dos números de especial?

Comment: Hola, he editado el post con el codigo para que mi pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: Esperen un momento, creo tener una idea.

Comment: Yo no entender ejercicio.... `print(f"0 y {random.randint(-5, 5)}")`.... propiedad cero de la multiplicación :)

Comment: Imagino que lo que están buscando es que trabajes con el ciclo `while` que a diferencia del `for`, puede iterar mientras no se de la condición que buscas.

Answer (score 1):

puedes utilizar un while

```
import  random

resultado = 1
while resultado != 0:
    a = random.randint(-5,5)
    b = random.randint(-5,5)
    resultado = (a * b)
    print(f"{a}*{b} = {resultado}")
```